# Random interior points of a demi circle

Tags: plotting, random, python

I am trying to write a code in Mathematica that allows me to find random points in this half circle by knowing the center and the radius. Each time I test something I find myself with a point out of this center, if there are resources or something that can help me I have done research but in vain?

[image]

Comment: In Python??? This is the StackExchange forum for Mathematica.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Mathematica or any of the other Wolfram Research software for which questions are accepted on this site.

Answer (score 5):

Are you asking for a solution with Mathematica instead of python?

If so, you can use RandomPoint. E.g., 100 points in the half-disk with radius 1 and centered at the origin:

```
r = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && x >= 0, {x, y}];
points = RandomPoint[r,100];
Show[Region[r], Graphics[Point[points]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
disksegment = DiskSegment[{0, 0}, 1, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}];

SeedRandom[1];
randompoints = Point[RandomPoint[disksegment, 100]];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[LightBlue], disksegment,
  PointSize[Medium], Black, randompoints }]
```

[image]